# Laravel 5.8. Target class [Controller] does not exist

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laragon

I am trying to create a view with four inputs which all enter that data into an sql database (using Laragon).

When I try click on the submit button I get an error saying "Target class [BikeController] does not exist."

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BikeController extends Controller
{
    function add(Request $req)
    {
print_r($req->input());
    }
}
```

Here is my routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use \app\Http\Controllers\BikeController;


Route::view('/add', 'addView');


Route::post('/add', 'BikeController@add');


Route::get('/', function (){

    return view('bikesView');

});

Route::get('/delete', function (){

    return view('deleteView');

});

Route::get('/edit', function (){

    return view('editView');

});
```

[Link to a pic of my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1jgz.png)

Currently I'm just trying to print out the data input on the screen but will eventually link it to mysql.

Comment: please share your actual code, not pictures of your code.

Comment: Please share the directory structure. Your controller may have a different path than namespace

Comment: Share your actual code and also the blade, where you send your POST.

Comment: On your controller, add this on the top `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=> Open App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php and uncomment this line

protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain more details, such that others can learn from it

Comment: If you create a new Laravel 8 project,there is no namespace prefix being applied to your route groups that your routes are loaded into. This causes en error that says Target class does not exist.

Comment: Please **edit your answer** to contain all relevant information

Comment: Though there is a mention of a $namespace property to be set on your RouteServiceProvider in the Release notes and commented in your RouteServiceProvider this does not have any effect on your routes. It is currently only for adding a namespace prefix for generating URLs to actions. So you can set this variable, but it by itself won't add these namespace prefixes, you would still have to make sure you would be using this variable when adding the namespace to the route groups.

Comment: With what the Upgrade Guide is showing the important part is that you are defining a namespace on your routes groups. Setting the $namespace variable by itself only helps in generating URLs to actions.

Again, and I can't stress this enough, the important part is setting the namespace for the route groups, which they just happen to be doing by referencing the member variable $namespace directly in the example.

Comment: // protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers'; that is commented on your RouteServiceProvider.php file that's why  error will generate Target class [Controller] does not exist and also not run your route so you can uncommented that line solved that problem. i can also face that error i hope help for you.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification **to your answer by editing it**. Don't use the comment section for such important explanation

Answer (score 0):

in your controller
change this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\BikeController;
```

to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

in namespace you just mention the path to the file

Comment: Tried this and didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

First check your `controller` if there is any error solve it, then check your `web.php`, if there is not an error and after that run those artisan commands for clearing the cache.

**Controller:**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BikeController extends Controller {
    function add(Request $req) {
        print_r($req->input());
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::view('/add', 'addView');
Route::post('/add', 'BikeController@add');
?>
```

Run the below artisan command:

```
//---Remove Routes Cache
php artisan route:clear;
//---Flush the application cache
php artisan cache:clear;
```

And if you want to regenerates the list of all your project classes run this composer command:

```
composer dump-autoload;
```

Comment: Tried this and didn't work :(

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Why should clearing some caches help in this situation?